# Does Android have an accessible error log

Tags: android, error-handling

I am (trying to) develop an application that plots a user's track.

To do this I'm using a LocationListener but it keeps crashing for no obvious reason.  I'm reasonably sure that there is some bad inter-action between this and other aspects of the application that is causing the problem but, unfortunately, by the very nature of the app, this only happens when I'm out and about and thus not tethered to a PC and so I'm finding it very difficult to track down.

I've scattered try/catches throughout the program but, so far, they have not trapped the error.

Does the Android operating system keep some sort of error log of application crashes and, if so, is it accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LogCat. Just add `Log.v`, `Log.d`, `Log.w`, or `Log.e` to your code and the log messages will show up in eclipse. V is verbose, d is debug, w is warning, and e is error.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of that but the problem occurs when I'm tracking my movement outside and so I don't have access to Eclipse or a PC at that point.  All I have is the device itself hence wondering whether the Android device, itself, contains any sort of logging.

Comment: You should be able to plug it in later and get these back off. I pretty sure there is a way to have LogCat display a larger number of the errors and such, but I am currently blanking on how to set it up.